# Disabling user interaction while showing loading animation if performing long tasks (network calls). Bad practice or Good practice?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it a good practice to disable user interaction while displaying a loading animation if time-consuming tasks are performed?

In poor network conditions, if user interaction is not disabled the user could e.g. press the same button multiple times to make countless network calls which will never finish and leaving the application in an inconsistent state.

What's the best way to approach this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Don't allow users to make another network call if there's already one in progress, you can either just ignore the taps, disable the buttons or use any other UI indicator to let the user know there's something going on.

I suggest having a look at some of the more popular apps and how they handle these situations, this has been worked over numerous times by now.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to show a loading activity anywhere (middle of screen with cover view all screen / beside the clicked button with disabling it) , it's not a good practice to overwhelm the app with similar network calls even if you disable the previous which will increase the response time and affect the app performance

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it depends.

Let's make an example using a critical process. Pressing a `Purchase` button to finalize the transaction in some e-commerce app can be described as such. You should display a screen-blocking progress dialog/activity indicator and inform the user about the API call progress (if possible).

On the other hand, if the API call is non-critical (for example querying the server for search results after the user typed something in the `search bar`) you should display a small activity indicator somewhere related to what is currently loading (in the searching example it'd be on the `search bar` or in the middle of the table view where the results will be loaded to). In this case, you should also straight up ignore the previous API call if the user types something new and start a new one.

Use your good judgement, there is no golden solution to this. Just think whether the process that is failable is important enough to block the whole app or not.